# how to terminate git process which is running currently?

Tags: git, terminate

```
$ git commit -m "45"
fatal: Unable to create 'F:/SoftifyBD/Projects/proj-4/CMS_Latest/contentmanagementsystem/.git/index.lock': File exists.
```

Another git process seems to be running in this repository, e.g.
an editor opened by 'git commit'. Please make sure all processes
are terminated then try again. If it still fails, a git process
may have crashed in this repository earlier:
remove the file manually to continue.
[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Git is not working properly. git commit -m "45" or git reset --hard or others not working. What should I do now?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62977204/git-is-not-working-properly-git-commit-m-45-or-git-reset-hard-or-others-no)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

When I faced the same **problem**. I found a solution and it is 
`rm -f ./.git/index.lock`
Please, try it. Thank you...

Comment: You’ve already answered this in another question. Please may you mark this one as a duplicate?

Comment: `rm .git/index.lock` try this if error with "-f"

Comment: rm : Cannot find path 'App\.git\index.lock' because it does not exist. I got that error when I run that command